# DataGrid Selected Item property getting executed on itemsource Change

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I have a Silverlight project and I am using the MVVM pattern.

I have a GridView control and I am assigning its ItemSource from a ViewModel. It's SelectedItem is bound to a ViewModel property.

On clicking a button I am updating the ItemSource of the Grid. But my problem now is the SelectedItem bound property is also getting executed when I update the ItemSource.

Is there a way that I can stop the SelectedItem property from getting executed on updating the ItemSource?

This is my DataGrid

```
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Width="400"
                                               Height="511" Visibility="Visible"
                                                SelectionMode="Single"
ItemsSource="{Binding DetailInfo, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem = {Binding SelectedAgent}                                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                               CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                                               CanUserSortColumns="True">
                            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailRank" Binding="{Binding Rank}" Header="#" Width="40"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailName" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Reps" Width="160"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailRevenue" Binding="{Binding Revenue, StringFormat=\{0:C0\}}" Header="Revenue" Width="70"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailProfit" Binding="{Binding Profit, StringFormat=\{0:C0\}}" Header="Profit" Width="58"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="detailMargin" Binding="{Binding Margin, StringFormat=\{0:P0\}}" Header="Margin" Width="55"/>
                            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

In my view model i have a property that is bind to the SelectedItem in Grid

```
private Agent _selectedAgent;

public Agent SelectedAgent
{
get{ return this._selectedAgent; }

set
{
this._selectedAgent = value;
RaisepropertyChanged("SelectedAgent");
}
}
```

Now when the ItemSource gets updated the SelectedAgent property gets executed again.

Comment: Can you post your XAML code and ViewModel code relevant to these bindings?

Comment: I Think You Should SelectedAgent = null When You Update Grid